# Import contacts to AD via CSV file

Tags: powershell, import, scripting, active-directory

So in my script, I create a new OU and import contacts into AD. The OU creation works fine, but none of the users are imported, and there aren't any errors saying it failed.

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "finance" -Path "DC=ucertify, DC=com"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\financePersonnel.csv

foreach ($user in $users) 
{


$samAccountname = $user.SamAccount
$FirstName     = $User.First_Name 
$LastName = $User.Last_Name
$PostalCode = $User.PostalCode
$MobilePhone = $User.MobilePhone
$OfficePhone = $User.OfficePhone
$City = $User.City
$Country = $User.Country



}
```

Comment: Where is the new-aduser command?

Comment: so I should add that after foreach?

Comment: It should be within the ForEach. Are you actually creating contacts or users?

Comment: creating users.

Comment: I think you're forgetting to actually add the new user in AD. You've created the variables to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why you should create variables for all the properties in the CSV file. Instead use them directly to build a hashtable which you can use for [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) the parameters to the `New-ADUser` cmdlet like below.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# the X.500 path of the Organizational Unit like:
$ouPath = "OU=Finance,DC=ucertify,DC=com"

# test if the OU already exists
if (!(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $ouPath)) {
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Finance" -Path $ouPath
}

Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\financePersonnel.csv | Foreach-Object {
    # create a hashtable with all the properties from the CSV
    # format: ParameterName = Value
    $userProps = @{
        'Name'           = ('{0} {1}' -f $_.First_Name, $_.Last_Name).Trim()
        'SamAccountName' = $_.SamAccount
        'GivenName'      = $_.First_Name 
        'Surname'        = $_.Last_Name
        'PostalCode'     = $_.PostalCode
        'MobilePhone'    = $_.MobilePhone
        'OfficePhone'    = $_.OfficePhone
        'City'           = $_.City
        'Country'        = $_.Country
        'Enabled'        = $true
        # I'm guessing you want the user created in the new OU
        # If you leave this out, the Path parameter defaults to the Users container. 
        'Path'          = $ouPath
    }

    # now splat these properties to the New-ADUser cmdlet
    New-ADUser @userProps
}
```

Lookup the [New-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps#required-parameters) cmdlet to see more properties you can set.